# Laravel 5.3 Eloquent working with SQL Server Varbinary data

Tags: sql-server, laravel-5.3, eloquent

I have two models with the same ID key that is a `Varbinary(18)` datatype in SQL Server. I am having trouble finding a way to deal with this datatype. I believe the main issue is that eloquent converts this data to a string. The database is existing with other applications depending on it so it cannot be modified.

Example:

TableFoo - first()->ID = 0x1234

TableBar - has an entry with ID 0x1234

```
$foo = App\TableFoo::first()->ID;
echo $foo 

//this echoes 1234 (removes the 0x)
// which makes the below return NULL

$bar = App\TableBar::where('ID', $foo)->get();
```

I have attempted to manually just add the 0x back on to the ID but this also does not find the ID in the second table and I believe this is because it is sending the value as a string.

If I manually do the query:

```
SELECT * FROM TableBar where ID=0x1234    //1 result returned
SELECT * FROM TableBar where ID='0x1234'  //0 results returned (how I think eloquent is trying to do the query)
```

I have seen in the docs that I can cast a datatype but none of the available types seem like they will help. This problem is also breaking Eloquent relationships.

My main question: is there a way to easily work with this datatype within Eloquent models or should I quit banging my head against a wall and go with a more manual query approach?

Comment: The big issue is that the varchar representation of varbinary 0x1234 is not '0x1234', but a two-character string -- ASCII(18) + '4'. You can actually compare that varchar value to the varbinary value and get a match. Try handling the field as `binary`, which Eloquent is supposed to handle.

Comment: I am not sure how to handle it as binary.  Binary is not listed as one of the data types for casting.  As soon as I use Eloquent to retrieve the data it is a string and I am new to Laravel so I could be missing something.

Comment: I have spent a lot of time trying to work through this and believe the issue is with Laravel.  It seems to handle this data type inconsistently.  The biggest problem I was having is it seems that some functions look at it as a binary datatype while others look at it as a binary.  So, when I would try to fix one thing it would break another.   Rather than continue to work through the problem I worked around it using DB::raw();